# How do I solve the following error?Input must be a character vector of any length or a list of character vectors, each of which has a length of 1

Tags: r, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am working on a R project. The data set I used is available at the following link
https://www.kaggle.com/ranjitha1/hotel-reviews-city-chennai/data

The code I have used is.

```
df1 = read.csv("chennai.csv", header = TRUE)
library(tidytext)
tidy_books <- df1 %>% unnest_tokens(word,Review_Text)
```

Here Review_Text is the text column. Yet, I get the following error.

> Error in check_input(x) :
> Input must be a character vector of any length or a list of character
> vectors, each of which has a length of 1.

Comment: You need `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in your `read.csv` statement.  Or use `read_csv` as you seem to be working in the tidyverse.

Comment: What I was about to say but in a more compact way. Consider checking out the structure of new data though before you work on it, i.e. `str(df1)`, this would have alerted you to the problem as well

Answer (score 20):

stringsAsFactors strikes again!

Your Review_Text column is a factor, not a character vector as the error message says the function requires.

I would strongly recommend using `readr::read_csv` over the default `read.csv` as it's faster and its defaults don't cause this problem. Otherwise, just set `stringsAsFactors` to `FALSE` and you're good:

```
> tidytext::unnest_tokens(readr::read_csv("chennai_reviews.csv"), word, Review_Text)
Parsed with column specification:
cols(
  Hotel_name = col_character(),
  Review_Title = col_character(),
  Review_Text = col_character(),
  Sentiment = col_character(),
  Rating_Percentage = col_character(),
  X6 = col_integer(),
  X7 = col_integer(),
  X8 = col_character(),
  X9 = col_character()
)
Warning: 1 parsing failure.
row # A tibble: 1 x 5 col     row   col   expected                                                                                                       actual expected   <int> <chr>      <chr>                                                                                                        <chr> actual 1  2262    X7 an integer "Expedia Booking  availability was  , only  for  Non-  AC ; ON REQUEST  OVER  PHONE got  it.\n\nRecommended" file # ... with 1 more variables: file <chr>

# A tibble: 179,883 x 9
            Hotel_name                          Review_Title Sentiment Rating_Percentage    X6    X7    X8    X9       word
                 <chr>                                 <chr>     <chr>             <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>      <chr>
 1 Accord Metropolitan Excellent comfortableness during stay         3               100    NA    NA  <NA>  <NA>        its
 2 Accord Metropolitan Excellent comfortableness during stay         3               100    NA    NA  <NA>  <NA>     really
 3 Accord Metropolitan Excellent comfortableness during stay         3               100    NA    NA  <NA>  <NA>       nice
 4 Accord Metropolitan Excellent comfortableness during stay         3               100    NA    NA  <NA>  <NA>      place
 5 Accord Metropolitan Excellent comfortableness during stay         3               100    NA    NA  <NA>  <NA>         to
 6 Accord Metropolitan Excellent comfortableness during stay         3               100    NA    NA  <NA>  <NA>       stay
 7 Accord Metropolitan Excellent comfortableness during stay         3               100    NA    NA  <NA>  <NA> especially
 8 Accord Metropolitan Excellent comfortableness during stay         3               100    NA    NA  <NA>  <NA>        for
 9 Accord Metropolitan Excellent comfortableness during stay         3               100    NA    NA  <NA>  <NA>   business
10 Accord Metropolitan Excellent comfortableness during stay         3               100    NA    NA  <NA>  <NA>        and
# ... with 179,873 more rows
Warning message:
Missing column names filled in: 'X6' [6], 'X7' [7], 'X8' [8], 'X9' [9]
```

or

```
> tidytext::unnest_tokens(read.csv("chennai_reviews.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE), word, Review_Text)
                                                Hotel_name
1                                      Accord Metropolitan
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        Review_Title
...snip...
```